# React Native Firebase Auth function

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I'm using react native crud application with using firebase real time storage. I use firebase auth functionality with email and password logging. but my firebase auth is not working. It gets more issues with firebase connection. I used this function to connect firebase.

```
  componentWillMount() {
      firebase.initializeApp({
       apiKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
       authDomain: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
       databaseURL: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
       projectId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
       storageBucket: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
       messagingSenderId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
     });
  }
```

My log in button auth functionality is looks like this one:

```
  state = { email: '', password: '', error: '' };

  onButtonPress() {
    const { email, password } = this.state;

    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .catch(() => {
      firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .catch(() => {
        this.setState({ error: 'Authenticaton Failed.' });
      });
    });
   }
```

I import firebase libraries like this:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import 'firebase/auth';
```

But this configurations are not working. It shows me this error:

```
undefined is not a function (evaluating 'firebase.auth()')
```

I used to get text input values this method:

```
    value={this.state.password}
    onChangeText={password => this.setState({ password })}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your firebase config only exists in your `componentDidMount`. Try like this:
  Create a file `<namefile>.js` wherever you want and add:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase'
import 'firebase/auth';

const config = {
    apiKey: "your key",
    authDomain: "domain",
    databaseURL: xxxx",
    projectId: "xxxx",
    storageBucket: "xxx",
    messagingSenderId: "xxxx"
};

if (!firebase.apps.length) {
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
}

const auth = firebase.auth();

export {
    auth
};
```

import `auth` in your component and in your button method change your code by:

```
auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword
```

it should work and every time you need to use `auth`, you just need to import it

Comment: should i want to add google_services json file into android directory?

Comment: I assume that work the same way as web...but you can change this and create a `const` inside of your component instead of creating a external file. It should work.

Comment: this works fine. i find a problem with my button function. i fixed it